# I had to hit submit button more than once to make the form work, (result load into colorbox popup)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, colorbox

The form validation works fine, so if u leave the email input blank and HIT submit ONCE, it will throw the error msg. BUT when u fill out the email [input] field, i had to HIT the "submitBtn" TWICE or sometimes even more to actually display the result.

so this is the script :

```
$('#RetrieveQuote2').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    },

    submitHandler: function() {
        $('input#submitBtn').bind('click', function() {
            var content = $("input#email").val();
            if (content == "abc@abc.com") {
                $('.quotenotfound').show();
                return false;
            } else {
                $('form#RetrieveQuote2').submit();

                formValidationSubmitted = true;

                if (!$('#RetrieveQuote2').valid()) {
                    $('.errorMessage').show();
                }

                $("input#submitBtn").colorbox({
                    href: function() {
                        var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');
                        var ser = $(this).parents('form').serialize(); //alert(url+'?'+ser);
                        return url + '?' + ser;
                    },
                    innerWidth: "780",
                    innerHeight: "450",
                    iframe: true
                });
            } // end of else
        });
    } // end of submitHandler
});
```

And below is the HTML form :

```
<form name="RetrieveQuote2" id="RetrieveQuote2" action="overlays/quotelist.php" method="get">
  <fieldset class="cf">
    <legend>email</legend>
    <label>Your Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" maxlength="25"/>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="RetrieveQuote" class="rqSubmitBtn" id="submitBtn" value="SUBMIT" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is a delay between your click and the response from server.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: You don't need to add the click handler. `validate` does that for you.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add a handler to the submit button **inside** of your submit handler.

So, on the first click, the validate handler is called (from the click handler that it adds automatically), and then your click handler is added, but not run.  The second click, you add **another** click handler, and then the one you added the first time is called.

The validate plugin should add the handler automatically for you.

Remove `$('input#submitBtn').bind('click', function() {` around your submit handler contents.

You also don't need `$('form#RetrieveQuote2').submit();`  This will also happen automatically after the submit handler.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/asrfV/

Comment: Jeff B, its working! BUT...once I include the colorbox plugin, i still had to HIT the submitBtn TWICE again :( any idea why ?

Comment: Same reason I think.  You are applying the colorbox **inside** of your submit handler.  Pull it outside of your `validate()` call.

Comment: Jeff, but I want to display the result inside Colorbox if it PASS the validate(), if i pull it out from submit Handler, isn't that means it will launch the Colorbox everytime I hit submit ?

Comment: But why are you applying the colorbox to the submit button?  Wouldn't you just want to call `$.colorbox({...})`?

Comment: Jeff, well pretty much Im trying to show the colorbox when Submitted. Where should I put it then ? I tried put the colorbox inside a new "success: function () { }", it works BUT the if / else statement above got ignored somehow.

Comment: The same place, but you don't want to apply it to anything.  Just call `$.colorbox({  <youroptionshere>  })`.  `submitHandler` is executed when you submit, so you are being redundant.